# iphone sdk communicate between thread

Tags: objective-c, ios4

My application has a second running thread. I need to achieve the following :

- Stop the separate thread gracefully from the main application thread
- Call a function on the main thread from the second thread to signal a result has been found and pass it to the main one.

I've found the following for the first task : share a global variable between the 2 threads ?
No idea how to achieve the second task. (NSNotificationCenter doesn't allow to pass objects ...)

I'm lunching the second thread like this `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(backGroudTask) toTarget:self withObject:nil];`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still searching for the best answer to this, but here is what I do:

Use NSLock to create a lock that prevents me from accessing the same variable on both threads.  Then use a BOOL to see if the main thread wants to initiate a stop.

in main thread do this

```
[myLock lock];
exitFlag = YES;
[myLock unlock];
```

in the other thread do this

```
endMe = NO;

while(!endMe)
{
  // do your task stuff

  [myLock lock];
  endMe = exitFlag;
  [myLock unlock];
}
```

For the second part of your question use the following:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(your_selector_name) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];
```

This will cause the your selector routine to run on the main thread.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

> (NSNotificationCenter doesn't allow to pass objects ...)

it does, but you have to add them to the userinfo of the notification

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myObject forKey:@"object"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object:self userInfo:userInfo];

- (void)foo:(NSNotification *)notification {
    id object = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"object"];
}
```